# Git autodeploy on Windows 2003 with WAMP

Tags: php, git, github, windows-server-2003

I work for a company that for some reason uses a Windows 2003 server with WAMP for its live product (please don't ask me why). Currently we have to push updates locally to github, manually connect to this production server with Remote Desktop Connection and pull.

We want to automate this proccess.

I have tried [github webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) with no success -> Couldn't find a way to create SSH keys for the system account (NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM), which is the one used by apache on that server solution. The project is currently cloned via HTTPS, so we could also try [saving credentials](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store) globally so that git won't prompt the local system account for password when trying to pull via PHP, but that seems like the worst possible solution security-wise.

Any ideas?

-- UPDATE --

We've decided not to worry about security implications right now. I then followed all the steps to save credentials for a new read-only user, but no success. I can see a .git-credentials file with the correct user/pass/url in:

C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile

All commands work (via browser) except for pull, fetch, etc.

Any more ideas?

-- UPDATE 2 --

I've now changed the wampapache service to run as an administrator account instead, which also has credentials stored on its "root" folder (~). It's the same account I can push/pull via cmd without user/pass prompts. But when I try via browser... No luck.

I'm now officially out of ideas.

Comment: Well, my first suggestion would be to find a new job.. My (slightly) more serious second suggestion is that I'm not sure it's worth worrying about the security implications of saving your credentials locally. If you create a user that only has read-access to the repo the worst that'll happen if your server is compromised is they'll get access to your source code, which they have at that point anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the input. We've came to the same conclusion regarding security. I've followed all the steps to save credentials for a new read-only user. It's working if I login to the server and manually pull: no user/password prompt. But it's not working if I try and access the URL used to execute git pull. All other commands that don't involve connecting to the github server do work (git status, etc) so it's probably still checking for credentials when it's the local system user. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found a solution!

Simply editting the git config file to add user:password to the url parameter under [remote "origin"] has done the job.

url = https://user:pass@github.com/organization/project.git

Comment: Thanks to the answer to this thread i finally figure out my problem and want to share it to everyone.
I was making a php script to update the repo.
What i did was to change the remote url origin like this `git remote set-url origin https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/user/project.git`

Comment: Vote up if it helped you. :)